# How to check is device camera enabled?

Tags: android, android-camera, device-admin

Is there any way to check is(/are) device camera(s) enabled ? If yes, what should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is that possibile, but it requires [Device Admin Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) . If you have that implemented, use that code :

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM =
    (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
if(mDPM.getCameraDisabled(adminComponentName))
{
//do something if camera is disabled
}
```

Comment: How do you get the `adminComponentName`?

Answer (score 2):

If by enabled, you mean open or currently in use, then yes, there is a way.

> Camera.open() will give you an Exception if Camera is in use.

So you can make use of this to check if the camera is enabled, currently in use or even if there is actually a camera.

```
/** how to get the camera object savely */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // try to get camera
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use) or does not exist
    }
    return c; // null will be returned if unavailable, or non existent
}
```

If the camera is currently in use but you want to use it, simply call

```
Camera.release();
```

and then use it yourself.

Comment: What if a user tries to open the camera via an Intent ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package manager to check if the device has a camera (if that's what you mean by enabled):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature(java.lang.String)

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
   // do your camera stuff
}
```